# Need help updating input field on selecting dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a currency exchange app and I've got the basic functionality done but the problem is that if I change the target currency while not changing the base currency input value, the target currency doesn't update.
I'd like it so that when I change any value in the second  element it automatically recalculates the rate based on what is already in the base input.

This is my first time asking a question on SO so be gentle.

Thank you.

You can find the project here: https://codepen.io/azdravkovski/pen/BddLeQ?editors=0010

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    //First AJAX call populates dropdown
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.fixer.io/latest?',
        success: function(data) {
            var currencyNoBase = Object.keys(data.rates);
            var currencyWithBase = currencyNoBase.concat(data.base).sort();
            //Populate dropdown lists with currency names
            $.each(currencyWithBase, function (val, text) {
                $('.currencies').append($('<option />').val(val).html(text));
            });
            //Set default currencies in base and target
            $('#base').val('8');
            $('#target').val('30');
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    //return selected base currency
    $('#curr1').on('input', function() {
        var base = $('#base option:selected').text();
        var url = 'https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=' + base;

//      Second AJAX call sets base currency
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(data2) {
                var target = $('#target option:selected').text();
                var curr1 = $('#curr1').val();
                var curr2 = $('#curr2').val();
                var converted = curr1 * data2.rates[target];

                $('#curr2').val(converted.toFixed(2));
                console.log(converted);

                //Clear input fields when changing currency
                $('#base').on('change', function() {
                    $('#curr1').val('');
                    $('#curr2').val('');
                })
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });

    });
```

And the html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Currency Exchange Rate App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rickshaw/1.6.1/rickshaw.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <!--INTERFACE-->
    <select name="base" class="currencies" id="base"></select>
    <input type="number" name="curr1" min="0" id="curr1" placeholder='0' step='.1'>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name="target" class="currencies" id="target"></select>
    <input type="number" name="curr2" min="0" id="curr2" placeholder='0' disabled>
    <!--    <button id="convert">Convert</button>-->
    <div id="test"></div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!--CHART-->
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <!--SCRIPTS-->

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rickshaw/1.6.1/rickshaw.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is largely there, I have added a **jQuery 'change' event** to the target currency option and by-and-large duplicated the second ajax call code. This results in the additional behaviour I understand you wanted.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2Tokoeka/Lyxwkux1/

Additional code:

```
// Event recognition for target currency option change
  $('select#target').on('change', function() {
    var base = $('#base option:selected').text();
    var url = 'https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=' + base;

  // Second AJAX call sets base currency
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data2) {
            var target = $('#target option:selected').text();
            var curr1 = $('#curr1').val();
            var curr2 = $('#curr2').val();
            var converted = curr1 * data2.rates[target];

            $('#curr2').val(converted.toFixed(2));
            console.log(converted);
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
  });
```

In terms of consolidating the code when you're ready, you could also make the second AJAX call a separate function and call it for each event and also extract the code section which clears the code when the base currency is changed into its own block. This is shown in the JS-Fiddle linked above.